# Combine JSON Object based on month PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

Hi I am having problem generating a json object that will return branch, cf of that month under 1 array like this:

Desired Output

```
 [{
"month": "Jan",
"Branch2":  550965.96 ,
"Branch1": 663134.44
}, {
"month": "Feb",
"Branch2": 472793.10,
"Branch1": 492784.54
}, {
"month": "March",
"Branch2": 394616.65,
"Branch1": 757639.93  
}, {
"month": "April",
"Branch2": 376403.65 ,
"Branch1": 569404.61  
}]
```

Here is my current Code

```
<?php
  $dbhost = 'localhost';
  $dbname = 'spmdb';  
  $dbuser = 'root';                  
  $dbpass = ''; 


  try{

    $dbcon = new PDO("mysql:host={$dbhost};dbname={$dbname}",$dbuser,$dbpass);
    $dbcon->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  }catch(PDOException $ex){

    die($ex->getMessage());
  }
$stmt = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT month.monthname,coll.branch,coll.cf FROM coll INNER JOIN month ON month.id = coll.`month` group by coll.month,coll.branch");
$stmt->execute();
$row1 = [];
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        extract($row);
        $row1[]= ['month' => $monthname, $branch => $cf];

    }
    echo json_encode($row1,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
?>
```

and currently ouputs this:

```
[{"month":"Jan","Branch4":40275}
,{"month":"Feb","Branch5":165173.91}
,{"month":"Feb","Branch1":93360.33}
,{"month":"Apr","Branch1":65415.75}]
```

Is there a way I could do this without modifying the mysql ?

Comment: How are you supposed to get 2 branches in one object, when you only have one branch in the row?

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY` when you have no aggregation functions like `SUM()` or `MAX()`?

Comment: Oh i forgot to add a sum thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `GROUP_CONCAT` and `CONCAT` to your query

```
$stmt = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT month.monthname, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(coll.branch,':',coll.cf)) as branchs FROM coll INNER JOIN month ON month.id = coll.`month` group by month.monthname");
$stmt->execute();
$row1 = [];
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $branchs = $row['branchs'];
    $branchs = explode(",",$branchs);
    $branch_data = array();
    foreach($branchs as $branch)
    {
        $branch = explode(":", $branch);
        $branch_data[$branch[0]] = $branch[1];
    }       
    $row1[] = array_merge(array('name' => $row['monthname']), $branch_data);

}
echo json_encode($row1,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Check SQLFiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/535f2/1

Comment: It was good but do you have idea on how to get the sum using grou concat?

Comment: @kkk - for what data you want to do sum?

Comment: coll.cf column is where i want to have the sum

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you need to change the month placing in the loop/building of the array.

```
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
     extract($row);
     $row1['month' => $monthname]= [$branch => $cf];

}
```

Comment: He's not trying to create an associative array.